# How does this simplification in this proof work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going through a proof right now and can't understand this one step:

\begin{align}
&= \frac{(1-p)(K+1)(-p^K)}{(1-p)^2}+\frac{1-p^{K+1}}{(1-p)^2} \\
&= \frac{1-p^{K+1}}{(1-p)^2}-\frac{(K+1)p^K}{(1-p)} \\
\end{align}

Can anybody please help me understand how this simplification works?

Comment: It looks to me that you should *subtract* the two terms in the second line instead of adding them, since all you've really done is to cancel a factor of $1-p$ from the numerator and denominator.

Comment: It's good that you acknowledged, and edited out, the error that @BarryCipra, and Ross Millikan pointed out to you, in your original post

Comment: You sound sarcastic @amWhy

Comment: Nope, just pointing out that you edited your question in a way that makes part of the answer given by Ross pointless and unexplainable.  So when you make edits, after answers have been provided, it is best to acknowledge in your post, that an edit has been made.  My comment simply compensated for your failure to acknowledge your edit.

Comment: If you would've looked closer you'd see I actually commented on Ross's answer saying I messed up right as I edited it. Try to not make sarcastic comments without taking a closer look in the future.

Comment: Nope, wrong again.  I stated what I observed.  Nothing sarcastic about that.  Other users who visit your question will also read Ross's answer, part of which touched on an issue you have since corrected.  So they may be confused....  Anyway, try not to be so overly reactive in the future.

Comment: Alright Mr math bigshot, if you think there's "Nothing sarcastic about" saying "its good" to something you think is wrong then you're in denial. Feel free to take this question down if you think future readers will be so confused.

Comment: Now now, Ms.MarksCode, calm down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have swapped the two terms in order.  The second term on the first line is identical to the first term on the second line.  They canceled a factor $(1-p)$ from the numerator and denominator of the first term to get the second, and dropped a minus sign.  The derivation is wrong.  The second term on the second line should be negative.

Comment: Oh I see. I actually messed up with writing the `+` instead of `-`. I didn't notice they swapped the order. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple simplification:

$\dfrac{(1-p)(K+1)(-p^K)}{(1-p)^2}=$

$=\dfrac{\require{cancel} \cancel{(1-p)}(K+1)(-p^K)}{\require{cancel} \cancel{(1-p)}(1-p)}$.